# Scrape data using lxml python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, lxml

I'm trying to create a function which scrape the league into a dictionary. However it seem to add an array into the dictionary instead of just the string. How come is this

html i'm trying to scrape:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend align="center">
        <a href="/dota2/events/297-the-summit-3">The Summit 3</a> 

   </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Python get_league function. self.url is the url where the html is

```
def get_league(self):
    request = requests.get(self.url)
    tree = html.fromstring(request.content)
    league = tree.xpath("//legend[@align='center']/a/text()")
    return league
```

adding into dictionary

```
data['league'] = self.get_league()[0]
```

The output in JSON

```
"league": [
"The Summit 3"
]
```

expected output

```
"league":"The Summit 3"
```

Comment: Something doesn't add up. This all works as expected using the code that you've posted... are you sure that you posted the right stuff? It's likely that you are calling `data['league'] = self.get_league()` without accessing item 0.

Comment: I believe `xpath` will return a list of elements, here you're taking the first element, but you want the text inside (but not sure how you're doing you JSON conversion). Did you try `return league[0].text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`findtext()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#findtext) would be handy in this case:

```
league = tree.findtext("//legend[@align='center']/a)")
```